# Query middle of string in MongoDB?

Tags: c++, mongodb

I need to run a query on a collection that contains a timestamp string ("YYYYMMDD:HH:MM:SS.SSSS").  I want to find all documents that have an hour less than 9 and hour greater than 14.  SQL offers the MID() function but I couldn't find an equivalent function.  How can I run this query in C++? If you don't know how to in C++ but in mongo shell let me know, I may be able to convert it to C++.

**UPDATE** 
Using JohnnyHK's suggestion below, I tried:

```
BSONObj queryafter = BSONObjBuilder().appendRegex("date", "........:0[0-8]").obj();
BSONObj queryafter = BSONObjBuilder().appendRegex("date", "........:[17-23]").obj();
c.update(dbcol, Query(querybefore), BSON("$set"<<BSON("noise"<<"true")), false, true);
```

It compiled but it didn't filter correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not terribly elegant, but you could do this in the shell using a regular expression:

```
db.test.find({ts: /....:..:..:0[5-8]/})
```

In the C++ driver you would build your query object with something like:

```
BSONObj query = BSONObjBuilder().appendRegex("ts", "....:..:..:0[5-8]").obj();
```

**UPDATE**

For your new requirements, it gets a little more involved, but still doable:

```
BSONObjBuilder().appendRegex("ts", "^........:(0[0-8]|1[5-9]|2[0-3]):..:").obj();
```

Comment: thanks, couldn't figure out how to convert it c++ :( . Does mongo c++ have a things that lets run shell code from within a c++ program? similar system(" ") for bash

Comment: @riotburn Not that I know of, no.  I added my guess at how to build this query using the C++ driver.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to use less than 9am and greater than 16 (4pm). So could I use appendRegex example for [09-16] and do QUERY(not <<query)?

Comment: tried your method, but I don't know if I used it correctly.  I added an update above.  Note, I corrected the format of the timestamp.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried running it but its returning results based on the seconds, not hours.

Comment: @riotburn Sorry, with the string format change it wasn't always matching the right part of the string.  See latest update.  Also, read up on regular expressions so you understand what this is doing.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I had tried playing around with adding some :..:.. after but I didn't get it right.  I'm guessing the . are wild cards.  What does ^ signify?

Comment: @riotburn `^` is the beginning of the string.  Here's an overview: http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own little way to do it in c++. If you have a string `"YYYY:MM:DD:HH:MM:SS.SSSS"` then you can tokenise it around the `:` using `strtok` or `stringstream`. Then use `atoi` to convert the hours into an `int` and finally compare with `<9 & >4`.

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) is a strtok example and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c) is a stringstream example.

EDIT: If you are confident of the position of the hours in the string (Which you must be right) Then you can also do it this way without a for loop:

```
string timestamp = yourTimestamp;
int hours = atoi(timestamp.substr(12, 2).c_str())
if (hours < 9 && hours > 4)
    your stuff
```

The explanation is, substr the section that contains the hours, turn it into a c string and convert to an int. Use the hours for compare.

Comment: I'm looking how to do it with database query.  I know how to do it in a for loop.  Looking for a nice one liner.  Do you know how to convert @JohnnyHK command below to C++?

Comment: @riotburn not in one line sorry.

Comment: doesn't necessarily have to be one line. Just want to avoid a for loop.

Comment: @riotburn I have edited the answer with a more succinct c++ segment, does that help?

Comment: I do know for a fact of the position of the hours in the string.  How do I use substring to int in a query?

Comment: @riotburn I am not sure, this is just the c++ way to do it with a string, if you need a special 'query' then this probably wont help you.

Comment: Thank you for help! Looking for the query way.